# CiviEvent: prevent registered users from changing their data

Tags: civievent, profile, forms

I'm running a CivicCRM installation od Drupal 7. I'm launching our first Event page with online registration - everything seems clear, except one thing: I'd like to prevent registered users from changing their data in the registration form. The form profile consists of Name, Surname and e-mail from Individual/Contact type, so registered users have these fields 'connected' with their crm record. Any change goes straight to the database and I'd like only anonymous users to edit these fields.
Can it be done just by configuration (ACLs maybe?) or does it require a custom plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [No Overwrite extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite) which prevents name changes on event registration forms.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for! It doesn't fit perfectly, but it won't be hard to adjust it to my needs. Just added 'email-Primary' to locked fields and for now it is enough :) Thanks very much!